# Write Stream to file in Windoes 8 class library

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am receiving a stream from a web api. I want to write this stream to a Storage file.

Comment: Could you give us some code that you have already? Something that you've already tried and done? No one wants to write code completely for you, but rather help and assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the **FileStram** and **FileName**

```
 public async Task SaveToLocalFolderAsync(Stream file, string fileName)
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (Stream outputStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
        }
    }
```

[`Saving a stream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638029/saving-a-stream-containing-an-image-to-local-folder-on-windows-phone-8)